# Run form-based code multiple times using vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Currently have a database containing the location of devices, and a form used to update the location of the devices and save a copy of their previous location. Ideally want to be able to input a list of "BoxNo" values (the ID field) and run the form multiple times with the same update on each record. Is this possible with VBA/SQL? Very low level of programming knowledge, any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: As requested by Gord Thompson, clarification on the form procedure.
On the form there is a boxnumber textbox, which is locked and changed only by using the search bar at the bottom of the page i.e in the navigation pane part, not the form itself, and a few text and comboboxes which correspond to fields related to the boxnumber. The user changes the relevant fields and then clicks an "update" button which runs the following code (The part relevant to the question is after the else statement).

```
Private Sub Update_Click()

'checks whether date updated
If DateUpdated = False Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a date", vbOKOnly, "Enter Date"


    'saves copy to "changes" table
Else
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Change_In_Location_tbl (Sm_ID,Given_To,On_Date, Comments)           VALUES ( " & Sm_ID.OldValue & ",'" & Currently_Held_by.OldValue & "','" &       Date_Given.OldValue & "','" & Comments.OldValue & "');"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    MsgBox "Update Complete", vbOKOnly
```

End If

End Sub

Comment: Can you share what you have done so far?

Comment: So presumably there is currently some form code that does some "stuff" for you, perhaps in a `Form_AfterUpdate()` procedure? If so, then you might get a better answer if you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18085447/edit) your question to show that code.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use a Do While loop.  Assuming you have the list of values in a table, open the recordset and loop through each value.

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset

set db = CurrentDB
set rec = db.OpenRecordSet ("Select * from MyTableWithBoxNoValues")

Do while rec.EOF = False

  ... process the BoxNo and save it
     (i.e., whatever your form is currently doing...)

  rec.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking originally but because a large amount of the procedure is done outside of code I didn't think it would work. Is there any way I could "codify" what's currently there so that I could run this loop?

Comment: OK, what you'd have to do is use a DLookup to get the relevant info from the table with the original info.  Or, you could put another loop inside my Do While loop that opens the original table, finds the record with the BoxNo that matches rec(0) and then runs an update statement.  I've got ideas in my head, but I'm too wrapped up in my own project at work to go into it.  Hopefully someone else comes along and takes it over the goal line for me.